# Combining results of Mysql Join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I am having a problem with Mysql join. I have two tables, a `center_contacts` table and a `center_contacts_notes`. `center_contacts_notes` are linked via a `contact_id` that is found in both tables.

Inside of `center_contacts_notes` there can be multiple rows per `contact_id` and I want to grab all of these and put them in a sub array of the results.

For example, here is what my `center_contacts_notes` table looks like:

```
contact_id   |   note
------------------------
1                test
2                hello
3                sup
1                moo
```

Here is where I am attempting to grab the data:

```
$this->db->select('center_contacts.id, FirstName, LastName, center_contacts_notes.note');
$this->db->from('center_contacts');
$this->db->join('center_contacts_notes', 'center_contacts_notes.contact_id = center_contacts.id');
```

Note that I am using Codeigniter 3.

Here is what I get from this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [FirstName] => Bob
    [LastName] => Smith
    [note] => test
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [FirstName] => Bob
    [LastName] => Smith
    [note] => moo
)
```

These are two different arrays inside of my results. This is impractical for my use as I need one array that contains both notes. Something like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [FirstName] => Bob
    [LastName] => Smith
    [note] => Array(test, moo)
)
```

Is this possible, and if so how would I accomplish it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried GROUP_CONCAT()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can get the two dimensional array like you've mentioned, but there is a workaround to get similar results. This might be helpful to you.

What you need to do is use `Group By` and `group_concat()`. `Group by` the table by `contact_id` and apply `group_concat()` on `center_contacts_notes.note`.

Your query should look like this.

```
$this->db->select('center_contacts.id, FirstName, LastName, GROUP_CONCAT(center_contacts_notes.note)');
$this->db->from('center_contacts');
$this->db->join('center_contacts_notes', 'center_contacts_notes.contact_id = center_contacts.id');
$this->db->group_by('center_contacts.id');
```

By default group_concat will concat the column by `,`. You can change it the following way.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(center_contacts_notes.note SEPARATOR 'YOUR_SEPARATOR_STRING')
```

This will return result as follow:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [FirstName] => Bob
    [LastName] => Smith
    [note] => test[YOUR_SEPARATOR_STRING] moo
)
```

You can use [PHP explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert note string into array by providing separator value.

Comment: Group_concat seems to have worked. It's not an array but I can still parse it as intended. Thanks.